# Use UniqueIdentifier column type and [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] for model's key doesn't work in EF Code First

Tags: c#, sql, database, asp.net-mvc-3, ef-code-first

This is my MVC model:

```
public class Link
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Shorted URL")]
    public string SURL { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("General Link")]
    public string OriginalURL { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Click Count")]
    public int ClickCount { get; set; }
}
```

and this is `LinkDBContext` class:

```
public class LinkDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Link> Links { get; set; }
}
```

when I want to add some data to database using this code:

```
    private string GetNewID(string url, string id)
    {
        LinkDBContext Links = new LinkDBContext();
        //id = "http://" + id;
        List<Link> link = Links.Links.Where(a => (a.OriginalURL == id && a.SURL == id)).ToList();
        if (link.Count == 0)
        {
            List<Link> LLinks = Links.Links.ToList<Link>();
            Link li = new Link();
            //li.ID = new Guid();
            li.ClickCount = 0;
            li.SURL = id;
            li.OriginalURL = url;
            Links.Links.Add(li);
            Links.SaveChanges();
            Links.Dispose();
            return id.ToString();
        }

        return GetNewID(url);
    }
```

I just get an exception that is: `Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ID', table 'GhiasiDB.dbo.Links'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.The statement has been terminated.`

what is the problem and how can I resolve it?

---

**update**

I changed the type of `ID` from `Guid` to `int` and when I tried again I got this exception from `List<Link> LLinks = Links.Links.ToList<Link>();` of `GetNewID` method:`The 'ID' property on 'Link' could not be set to a 'Guid' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'Int32'.`
and I don't know where did it come from. I changed all `Guid`es to `int`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you allowed EF to generate the tables it would create the PK with a default value set to `(newid())`. You can set it manually if you designed the database first.

Comment: ID column is uniqeidentifire and it's PK but I still get exception!

Comment: @ahmadalishafiee Did you set the `Default Value or Binding` property of the `ID` column in your table to `(newid())`?

Answer (score 2):

If the table already existed before adding `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]`, then remove the `DbSet`, run `Update-Database`, add the `DbSet` again, finally run another `Update-Database`.

At least that's what fixed it for me.

Comment: this is exactly the issue! THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because `Guid` and *Identity* are not compatible. How do you think to auto-increment Guid?

Maybe changing `Id` to `int` could help you

Answer (score 0):

**Guid** is structure type i.e value type. You can not assign null to value type. If you want this than in that case you can use "**?**" after type in declaration.

```
  public Guid? ID { get; set; }
```

if this still does not help, try an **int**